# How to via Button events, send AJAX requests,to the same page and for PHP catch the events[PHP]

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, events

I do have an `Calendar` application in which the month should be displayed by the chosen button - [Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAoq2.png).

Big part of the calendar was developed by https://codeshack.io/event-calendar-php/ and it is in `PHP`.

It is included in the HTML page this way:

**index.php**

```
<?php
  include 'Calendar.php';
  $calendar = new Calendar('2023-05-12');
  $calendar->add_event('Birthday', '2023-05-03', 1, 'green');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Event Calendar</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navtop">
            <div>
                <h1>Event Calendar</h1>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="content home">
            <?=$calendar?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For the sake of simplicity in the `php calendar file` a `month-navigation menu` was also added that rendered looks like this: [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ukqY.png)

---

**How it should work**:

- The choosing of the month should be done via the `month-buttons`, hence the `buttons` in the `menu` should register a `click`, then depending on the chosen month should regenerate the `calendar`.

---

**The idea:**

- When a month `button` is clicked, an `AJAX Request` should be sent, that inserts some data into `$_POST` `PHP` variable
- The changed `$_POST`, variable is going to trigger an `PHP` Code
- `PHP` Code should then regenerate the `calendar` via the given data.

---

**The implementation:**

The beginning of the `file` was changed to:

```
function generateCalendar ($date) {
  $calendar = new Calendar($date);
  $calendar->add_event('Birthday', '2023-05-03', 1, 'green');
}
```

The script, that checks if a month was clicked, was added into `index.php`

```
<script>
    $(".btn-outline-dark").click(function(oEvent) {
        const sMonth = oEvent.currentTarget.attributes["data-month"].value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {month: sMonth},
            success: function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // console.log(error);
            }
        });
        // console.log("Hallo Welt");
    })
</script>
```

The following was also added to the `index.php`, to regenarte the `calendar`.

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
  if (isset($_POST["month"])) {
    generateCalendar($_POST["month"]);
  }
?>
```

---

**Issues**

- Eventho, the request was sent and is successful, the `isset($_POST["month"])`, is not executed
- The network tab showcases that the ajax request was sent, as well as the new `index.php` page mentioned does execute the php code mentioned above.
- However the present page remains empty.

---

**What i did, to solve this issue:**

- Saving the variable as a cookie

```
if (isset($_POST['month'])) {
    setcookie('month', $_POST['month'], time() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
}
```

Doesn't work

---

**Question**:

- How to catch an post-request event with PHP, instantaneously? Or alternatively how to save an cookie, so that it could be used later on ?

Best Regards,
Roman

Comment: `success: function (response)` is empty so even if the php code executes you aren't doing anything with the results, you need some JS to update your page